# window.opener.parent.focus(); IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I open one pop-up when I click on a button of my site.

```
$('.play-direct button').on("click", function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  popup = window.open(window.location.origin + '/player', 'MonPlayer', 'menubar=no, resizable=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no, width=321, height=223');
});
```

My pop-up is an audio player which contains a js with a button which allows me to return the focus on the main site.

```
$("#return-main").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //window.focus();
  //window.blur();
  //window.open('', window.opener.name);
  //window.opener.parent.focus();
  //window.opener.opener.focus();
  //parent.opener.focus();
  window.focus(window.opener.name);
});
```

When I click on the button of pop-up by being on my computer or on a device Android it works well. My pop-up remains open with my player in reading and the focus is on the main site. 
However, when I test under environment IOS (IPhone, IPad, Safari), the button of pop-up makes nothing. The focus stays on pop-up and I do not obtain error. I tried several way (cf. pop-up code) but none works.

Anybody has already had this kind of problem ?

Romest

Comment: check the .on("click") - there is a typo - of your second provided snippet and why do you have some much comments in the second snippet?